# jQuery mouseleave not working

Tags: jquery

Ok so basically, Ive got a smaller div (overlay) thats hidden that shows/hides when the mouse hovers over the main div (box). So when the mouse hovers , the overlay div slides up, but when the mouse leaves the box div the overlay remains and does not slide back down.

**CSS**

```
.box {border:1px red solid; width:250px; height:230px; position:relative; overflow:hidden}      
.overlay {position:absolute; background-color:red;  width:100%; height:50px; bottom:-60px}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="box"><div class="overlay">content</div></div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.box').hover(function(){
    $('.overlay').animate({top:"180px"});
}); 

$('.box').mouseleave(function(){
    $('.overlay').animate({bottom:"180px"});  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mouseleave` should goto the opposite value of your initial animate:

```
$('.overlay').animate({top:"-180px"});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S4dsk/

Comment: kinda does what I want, but when the mouseleaves is there a way to make it slide back down instead of sliding upwards? like, slide up on enter, then slide down on leave?

Comment: @Pascoe_ -- Set the `top` to be your original value plus the height of the container: `top: 230px` will slide it downward out of the container

Comment: brillient! works great. thanks for all the help guys!

Comment: @Pascoe_ -- be sure to mark the answer as correct if it helped and accomplished what ya needed! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.box').hover(function(){

    $('.overlay').animate({top:"180px"});

},function(){

    $('.overlay').animate({bottom:"180px"});

});
```

Comment: Doesn't change the outcome

Comment: I have just suggest mouseleave event. I thought your mouse leave event was not firing